# Why label with border radius and border make some outside corner border?

Tags: html, css

I need help with this https://jsfiddle.net/ymony0qy/.

```css
  .row {
    height: 50px;
    display:table-row;
    
}
.col-left, .col-right {
    
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.col-left{
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FFCC66 ;
  text-align: center;
}

.col-left .content span{
  font-size: 20px;  
}

.lab-variace {
    background: #ff6800;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-collapse: separate;
    padding: 1.2em;
    margin: 0.2em;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 220px;
    display: table-cell;
    border: 5px #fff solid;
    height: 60px;
}

.lab-variace:hover {
    background:#ccc;   
}

.radio-varia:checked + .lab-variace{
  background: red;
}

.variace{
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.radio-varia{
  visibility: hidden !important; 
  position: absolute !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="variace">
      <div class="row">
      <input type="radio" name="pred_conf" id="zaklad" onclick="pocitej_vps()" value="zaklad" class="radio-varia"><label class="lab-variace" for="zaklad">Var 1<br />xx<br />xx<br />x</label>
   <input type="radio" name="pred_conf" id="stred" onclick="pocitej_vps()" value="stred" class="radio-varia"><label class="lab-variace" for="stred">Var 1<br />xx<br />xx<br />x</label>
      </div><div class="row">
   <input type="radio" name="pred_conf" id="extra" onclick="pocitej_vps()" value="extra" class="radio-varia"><label class="lab-variace" for="extra">Var 1<br />xx<br />xx<br />x</label>
      <input type="radio" name="pred_conf" id="own" checked="checked" onclick="pocitej_vps()" value="own" class="radio-varia"><label class="lab-variace" for="own">Var 1<br />xx<br />xx<br />x<br /><br /><br /></label>
      </div></div>
```

[image: bad corners]

As you can see on every corner is some little dotted outside line. When I delete *border: 5px #fff solid;* it is ok. Any help for it? Thanks

Comment: It's because you reached the pixel limit. What you see is the maximum achievable with pixels. Doing something more precise would need vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `background-clip:padding-box` on your `.lab-variace` and `.radio-varia:checked + .lab-variace` classes.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9kuxrk2b/Fiddle)

[More info on background-clip](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-clip/)